# In Laflet map, When click outside of the map, how to close opend popup

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, lit

I am developing cms widgets using lit-element and it contains leaflet maps. we open popups inside the map when we click on the marker. and close them inside the map. ***But the problem is how to close those opened leaflet marker popups when click outside of the leaflet map ?***

. I was looking for the answer for long time. But i couldn't find any. Please help me .. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fastest way to close all popups https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-closepopup

Answer (score 0):

[documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-openpopup) stated may use closePopup function to closes the popup previously opened with openPopup. Based on my understanding to the documentation, you may try to store openPopup as a variable, trigger function to close the popup once clicking outside the map.

```
var boo = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
.bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
.openPopup();

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).closePopup(boo);
```